# How to add global barButtonItems to custom UINavigationBar?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am currently trying to create a custom **UINavigationBar** Subclass. 
What i want to achieve is that all custom navigationbars inside my app should have a couple of *barbuttonitems* in common. But it should still be possible to define left or .rightbarItems on the `navigationItem` in code.

What i tried so far is that subclassed the `UINavigationBar` and played around with all methods and delegate callbacks i could potentially use to change the navigationItem. There are methods like

```
setItems:animated:
setItems:
navigationBar:didPushitem etc.
```

.. which could be used to modify the `navigationItem` somehow.
But there is no callback which can be used to change the item initially.

What i basically want to know is how it is possible to change `navigationItem` initially before it is being pushed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself using 
`willShowViewController` of the `UINavigationControllerDelegateProtocol` 
to modify the navigationItem